# display different component on same mxml page

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

i want to implement this.
(http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=1;illustIndex=0;sampleId=0) 
type of structure in my application.how can i display different component in different parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout uses [divided boxes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layouts_07.html).  The left side is filled with a tree and the right side changes dynamically based on the selection on the left.

Tour De Flex doesn't display any content, it just links to it.  So, I'm sure they are loading up information from a database to populate the tree which also includes enough information to create the display on the right.  I would assume they use ActionScript.

Comment: thanks for this...but they are also loading dynamic contain.i have find custom component iframe "http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/" is there any adobe component alternative for this iframe.???

Comment: @user594979 As far as I know Adobe doesn't provide an iFrame component.  Drumbeat Insight has a commercial one.  The AIR version of Tour De Flex uses the AIR HTML component which is not available in web based apps.

Comment: how can i load different swf component dynamicaly as shown in example.(upper right part) http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=1;illustIndex=0;sampleId=0

Comment: @user594979 I'm not sure how the web based version of Tour De Flex does it (but the non-web based one uses the AIR HTML Tag and just embeds the HTML page w/ the samples.  You might try the SWFLoader class.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use states on the right side panel, with one state per component.  When you select an option on the left, change the state on the right.

That may not scale well.  In that case, you'll have to create, add, and remove components via actionscript.

Comment: in given example they are loading swf files dynmically. how to load differnt swf files ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the sample code for similar layout [here](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm)!